# Specflow: how to use common step definition in two different projects?

Tags: selenium, .net-core, automation, cucumber, specflow

My project consists of as follows.

1. Specscore.website1
2. Specscore.website2
3. SpecscoreCommon

I keep my common methods and classes in the common project. I use these methods by calling them from within the common project in website1 and website2 projects.
I also want to keep my common steps in common project. But when I define it in common project I get the following error.

No matching step definition found for one or more steps.

how can I define my common steps in common project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Specflow - BeforeScenario hook is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507198/c-sharp-specflow-beforescenario-hook-is-not-being-called)

Comment: See [Bindings from External Assemblies](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies.html) in the SpecFlow docs.